# kubeadm upgrade plan warning when updaten from 1.23 to 1.24 on ubuntu

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

A few weeks ago I upgraded kubernetes 1.22 to 1.23. I'm using containerd as container runtime a long time. Os is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Now when upgrading from 1.23 to 1.24 `kubeadm upgrade plan` show warning about runtime as

```
W0917 12:14:33.970744   27728 initconfiguration.go:120] Usage of CRI endpoints without URL scheme is deprecated and can cause kubelet errors in the future. Automatically prepending scheme "unix" to the "criSocket" with value "/run/containerd/containerd.sock". Please update your configuration!
```

I have made quite lot of research to find out, where to add/fix setting to get out of this warning. Config-changes I have made at least `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env` and `/etc/crictl.yaml` files, but there is no success. Anybody?

This was copied from stack overflow, I made it there some reason :-(
Before it was closed, Ola Ekdahl add anwer to this - thank's. I add it here.

```
Run this command on your control plane and nodes.

sudo crictl config \
--set runtime-endpoint=unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock \
--set image-endpoint=unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

This does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After installing 1.24-->1.25 this message disappear. Now at version 1.29 and no messages at any step.